# I don't understand why i didn't find element

Tags: java, webclient, htmlelements

I want to get result searching. But I get `null`.

**my code:**

```
  public class Example{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String searchQuery = "Лукашенко";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            HtmlPage page;
            try {
                String searchUrl = "http://search.tut.by/?status=1&ru=1&encoding=1&page=0&how=rlv&query=" + URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "windows-1251");
                page = client.getPage(searchUrl);
                System.out.println(page.getPage());
                System.out.println(getByXPath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ol/li[1]"));

                List<HtmlElement> items = (List<HtmlElement>) 
   page.getByXPath("(.//li[@class=\"b-results__li\"])");
                System.out.println(items.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

When I run code I get:

HtmlPage(http://search.tut.by/?status=1&ru=1&encoding=1&page=0&how=rlv&query=%CB%F3%EA%E0%F8%E5%ED%EA%EE)@2039810346
        []
        []

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s  
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Where are the elements?
I checked my XPath.

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: Well, we neither know the html of your page (so we can't tell whether the xpath is correct) nor do we know the implementation of `getByXPath(String)` so we can't tell what that method is doing.